# Event Listener when the page reloads

Tags: service-cloud-console

i have a cti phone that uses

```
sforce.console.addEventListener(sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.OPEN_TAB, checkCases);
```

to see if a case has been opened in the service console. Im wondering what will be the event to call in the addEventListener if the case page has been updated.

Thanks,